# MSAL Node service & The Partner Center API

Tags: node.js, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

## tl;dr

Using `msal-node` in a *non*-interactive service, how do I authorize as an MFA-enabled user *once* and never (or very rarely) have to authorize as that user again? Particularly when making requests to the Partner Center API.

### longer version

I've been trying to create a backend service (i.e. a daemon) in NodeJS that interacts with the Microsoft Partner Center API. However, I can't find an officially supported way to do this without constant user interaction.

Based on [most documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-acquire-cache-tokens#confidential-client-applications) I could find, services without *any* user interaction are meant to use the "client credentials" flow. This works great for other Azure APIs, but doesn't seem to work in the Partner Center API despite what [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/partner-center-authentication#app-only-authentication) say.

What does work, and what I'm forced to do, is login as a user instead. However, because all users are MFA-enabled, I have to follow the approach outlined [in these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/enable-secure-app-model#rest) where I manually login as a user and do a one-time exchange for a refresh token. I then save this to a file and the daemon can then continually exchange it for both an access token as well as an updated refresh token.

But it doesn't look like `msal-node` supports using just the refresh token out-of-the-box. The only instance method that accepts one as a parameter is `.acquireTokenByRefreshToken()` which does return an access token (see [this sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/6650148dae23ec568619a4ed8fe2a9077d1e0e8c/samples/msal-node-samples/refresh-token/index.js#L22-L26)) but does *not* update the instance's internal cache or return a new refresh token, so the existing refresh token would expire prematurely. It also seems to be deprecated in favor of `.acquireTokenSilent()`, but that method requires the instance's internal cache to already be populated with authentication data. However, I don't see any public methods to manually set the internal cache's data, and it's only set automatically after calling methods like `.acquireTokenByCode()` which accept short-lived tokens generated after user login. And again, since all users are MFA-enabled, that would require user interaction every time the service restarted.

So a bit of a chicken-or-the-egg problem. Any help is appreciated, I've been going nuts reading this much MS documentation and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting this question, I figured out how to do this in `msal-node` natively. By default `msal-node` only caches tokens in memory, which isn't great for non-interactive services that inevitably restart.

Luckily the config parameter of a `msal-node` client app has an optional `cache.cachePlugin` property to define your own cache getter/setter. As [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-node-migration#enable-token-caching) documentation shows (ignore the "ADAL" part), you can use this to fetch/store tokens on the disk. With this you can now just call `acquireTokenSilent` anytime you need a *new* access token, and it'll automatically retrieve and/or refresh one for you, even if your service restarts. Here's an example module with a function to get an access token for the cached user account, and a function to cache a user account in the first place:

**auth.js**

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const msal = require('@azure/msal-node');

const CLIENT_ID = "MY-CLIENT-ID";
const CLIENT_SECRET = "MY-CLIENT-SECRET";
const CACHE_PATH = "/PATH/TO/CACHE/FILE";
const SCOPES = ["MY-REQUEST-SCOPE(S)"]; // e.g. "https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/.default", "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default", etc.

const CCA = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication({
    auth: { clientId: CLIENT_ID, clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET },
    cache: {
        cachePlugin: {
            // Read the disk for tokens
            beforeCacheAccess: async (context) => context.tokenCache.deserialize(await fs.promises.readFile(CACHE_PATH, 'utf-8')),
            // Write the token back to the disk if it was refreshed
            afterCacheAccess: (context) => context.cacheHasChanged ? fs.promises.writeFile(CACHE_PATH, context.tokenCache.serialize()) : null
        }
    }
});


/**
 * Add the account that generated the authCode to the disk cache. 
 * @param {String} authCode - The code in the query of the MS redirect after the successful one-time user login
 * @param {String} redirectUri - The URL that MS redirects to after the one-time user authentication
 */
exports.addAccountToCache = async (authCode, redirectUri) => {
    await CCA.acquireTokenByCode({
        redirectUri: redirectUri,
        scopes: ["user.read"],
        code: authCode
    });
};


var lastTokenRes;
/**
 * Gets a new or existing access token for a user account, and automatically handles refreshing when needed. 
 */
exports.getAccessToken = async () => {
    // Checking token expiration ourselves may seem redundant since calling .acquireTokenSilent() will do that on its own
    // anyway, but each call to it takes at least 300ms regardless of whether or not a valid token is in the cache
    if (!lastTokenRes || lastTokenRes.expiresOn >= Date.now()) {
        let firstAccount = await CCA.getTokenCache().getAllAccounts()[0];
        lastTokenRes = await CCA.acquireTokenSilent({
            account: firstAccount,
            scopes: SCOPES
        });
    }

    return lastTokenRes.accessToken;
}
```

Caching a user account requires calling `addAccountToCache` with an authorization code for that user. Said code is generated via the authorization-code-flow described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow), and should only need to be done once so long as the service calls `getAccessToken` at least once every 90 days. For redundancy in a production setting, I'd also create an express route to sign-in a user account and generate their auth codes like in [this sample app](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-node-samples/auth-code), but manually works too since you can just pass around the generated cache file as needed.

Answer (score 1):

As [this official doc](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-common/docs/request.md#refresh-token-flow) indicates:

> The refresh token is never returned to the user in a response

So it is by design that you can't get and renew a refresh token this way.

As a workaround, you can call Azure ad `/token` endpoint API directly to get a new refresh token by an old one and then replace the old one in your file.
Details see [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#refresh-the-access-token). Though the title is `refresh the access token`, you can get a new refresh token in every single request:
[image]

So that you can refresh your refresh token when it is about to expire.

Comment: This is a good workaround for sure, and the one I was going to use to opt for if I didn't discover a way to take advantage of the built-in refresh/caching of `msal-node`, but I just figured out a proper way to access the internal cache directly, so I don't have to worry about implementing a custom auto-refresh. I'll post my answer after I work it out a bit further.

Comment: @user3781737 that's great, pls kindly share it after you work it out :)

Comment: Just shared it. Hopefully it's helpful to someone else!